# Phaser - how to use it as CountDownLatch(1)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, phaser

I understand I could simply use `CountDownLatch` directly, however, as an excercise and to understand `Phaser` better, I would like to use it instead of `COuntDownLatch`.

Thus, I would create N number of awaiters, and one thread that needs to flip the latch. All awaiters, if arrive before the flip, would block, however after the latch is counted-down, then all subsequent `await()` returns instantly.

WIth `Phaser` I am not sure how to achieve this... Barrier is easy, as we have N + 1 threads, each arriving and awaiting. However, to make sure that no thread will await *after* the first phase, somehow eludes me.

The only way I could come up with, which is not nice, is as follows:

```
Phaser p = new Phaser(1);
int phase = p.getPhase();
....
// thread that awaits()
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    ....
    p.awaitAdvance(phase)
}
```

And the other thread simply advances the phaser to next phase. This is not ideal, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with @tiago-cogumbreiro's answer. In fact, `Phaser` can be used to simulate behavior of `CountDownLatch`.

You can achieve it using Phaser's `arrive()` method. It won't wait for other threads to arrive. Hence, `CountDownLatch` behavior can be achieved.

Phaser's `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()` makes thread in which it is called to wait, till other threads/parties arrive. Hence, this method can be used to simulate behavior of `CyclicBarrier`.

Below is source code which simulates behaviour of `CountDownLatch(3)` using `Phaser`. If you use only one `WorkerThread`, you can simulate `CountDownLatch(1)`

If you replace, `arrive()` method with `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()` method, below code would simulate `CyclicBarrier`.

```
public class PhaserAsCountDownLatch {

    static Phaser phaser = new Phaser(3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        new WorkerThread2().start();
        new WorkerThread3().start();
        new WorkerThread().start();
        
        //waits till phase 0 is completed and phase is advanced to next.
        phaser.awaitAdvance(0); 
        
        System.out.println("\nFROM MAIN THREAD: PHASE 0 COMPLETED");
        System.out.println("FROM MAIN THREAD: PHASE ADVANCED TO 1");
        System.out.println("MAIN THREAD ENDS HERE\n");
    }

    static class WorkerThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +  ", BEFORE ARRIVING val is: " + i);
            }
        
            phaser.arrive();
        
            System.out.println("ARRIVED tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }

    static class WorkerThread2 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
        
            //won't wait for other threads to arrive. Hence, CountDownLatch behaviour can be achieved
            phaser.arrive();
        
            System.out.println("ARRIVED tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            for (int i = 200; i < 231; i++) {
                System.out.println("tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +  " AFTER ARRIVING. val is: " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    static class WorkerThread3 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
        
            //won't wait for other threads to arrive. Hence, CountDownLatch behaviour can be achieved
            phaser.arrive();
        
            System.out.println("ARRIVED tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            for (int i = 300; i < 331; i++) {
                System.out.println("tid: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +  " AFTER ARRIVING. val is: " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: In this context use `Phaser.arriveAndDeregister()` for a non-blocking signal to the waiters of the phaser, which corresponds to operation `CountDownLatch.countDown()`.**

**`Phaser` and `CountDownLatch`.** The first thing to clarify is that a `Phaser` **cannot** generally encode a `CountDownLatch`. The tasks synchronizing with a `Phaser` must all wait for each other (all-to-all synchronization). In a `CountDownLatch`, there is a group of tasks that awaits some other task to open the latch.

**`Phaser` and `CyclicBarrier`.** Both of these mechanisms are used for all-to-all synchronization. The two differences between them are: 1) a `Phaser` the set of tasks using the phaser may grow during the life cycle of the phaser, whereas in a `CyclicBarrier` the number of participants is **fixed**; 2) with `Phasers`, a task may notify other members (participants) and not wait as long as it deregisters from that phaser, whereas all tasks using the cyclic barrier can only wait-and-notify.

**Encoding a `CountDownLatch` with a `Phaser`.** To encode a CountDownLatch(1) with a phaser you need to keep in mind the following:

1. Number of parties = number of waiters + 1: The number of registered parties, either via `new Phaser(PARTIES_COUNT)` or via `Phaser.register`.
2. `CountDown.await()` = `Phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance()`
3. `CountDown.countDown()` = `Phaser.arriveAndDeregister()`

**Example.** Suppose you want the child task to wait for the parent's task signal. Using `CountDownLatch` you would write:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class CountDownExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                l.await();
                System.out.println("Child: running");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("Parent: waiting a bit.");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        l.countDown();
    }
}
```

Using a `Phaser` you would write:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class PhaserExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Phaser ph = new Phaser(2); // 2 parties = 1 signaler and 1 waiter
        new Thread(() -> {
            ph.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            System.out.println("Child: running");
        }).start();
        System.out.println("Parent: waiting a bit.");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        ph.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
}
```

You might want to look at [this post for another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637030/2327050).

Comment: That is not correct - in your example you assume that the waiters number is known in advance, which is not the case in COuntdownLatch, and that solution is not a general purpose one

Comment: The point is that there is **no general encoding** of using juc.Phasers to encode CountdownLatches. So either a) we sacrifice expressiveness and introduce contention (by opting for an all-to-all synchronization), or we need to know how many participants beforehand and get the same level of contention.

Comment: I've updated the text to reflect the discussion above.