# How to set countdownlatch for unknown number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have to start unknown number of threads then wait or all threads to finish their job. I am using executor service. I tried using countdownlatch - so that I may wait till countdown is zero. 
 But there is no way I can get number of threads I have started. Can someone give me any idea how may I achieve this ?

Comment: Why not use [`Future`s](https://www.baeldung.com/java-future) instead?

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried. Not able to understand the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. I came across the answer, and it helped. Sharing a link for reference.
[Flexible CountDownLatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636194/flexible-countdownlatch)

Answer (score 0):

In case that you want combine a List of `CompletableFutures`, you can do this :

```
// Waits for *all* futures to complete and returns a list of results.
// If *any* future completes exceptionally then the resulting future will also complete exceptionally.

public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> all(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    CompletableFuture[] cfs = futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]);

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(cfs)
            .thenApply(ignored -> futures.stream()
                                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
}
```

For more details on Future & CompletableFuture, useful links:

1. Future: https://www.baeldung.com/java-future
2. CompletableFuture: https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture
3. CompletableFuture: https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/
4. [Waiting on a list of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348248/waiting-on-a-list-of-future)